I just made a chess bot. Is there any way for how to calculate the ELO of my bot?
I just made a chess bot. Is there any way for how to calculate the ELO of my bot?
I need to make it easy and fast. It's just a weak chess bot I build in Scratch that I built for like 3 days. It would be really nice if you found a link to test my bot. Chess.com does have it in the Game Review but I don't have Premium so I can only test it once a day (easy but slow). :)

Please use the search function before posting to make sure your question hasn't been asked before.
